# Jagged Edges in Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am getting jagged edges in the rendered view. In viewport the edges are smooth.

Using Eevee render engine.
Can someone help.

[image]

Comment: I cant confirm that. If you press 1 on numpad to see render at zoom 100% it is fine, also scale up if fine. only scale down produce this jagging at some levels that is normal for pixels recalculation in viewer. If you still think it is not working as expected post a blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to let as see.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the resolution of your render. Try going to the Output Properties tab under the "Dimensions" section and increase the resolution of your render. Also ensure that the resolution % is set to 100 to achieve the maximum quality.

When moving around in the viewport, resolution is mainly limited by your monitor or computer screen, but when you render a scene, the resolution of the camera is now the limiting factor to how sharp your rendered image will appear. Increasing it should help produce a higher quality image and reduce how much you are able to see the jagged edges.

Comment: Unfortunately increasing the resolution under dimensions doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are seeing here is Z-figthing due to floating point precision limitations.

Try to increase the camera clip start and/or decrease the camera clip end values.
The reason why your viewport image doesn't have this problem is because the clip start and end values are controlled seperately for viewport and render.