# Anti-Aliasing in Eevee has no effect (still jagged edges)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, antialiasing

I'm wondering why anti-aliasing is not working for me in Eeevee using Blender 3.6.1 (still an issue in Blender 4.0.0). See the minimal reproducible Blender file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lhuWx4hwVFt2TwurKdDwDbf8eiXVhQUz/view).

Here are some examples. First, this is what I get with 256 render samples. I use the [`Anti-Aliasing Node`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/anti_aliasing.html) which seems to not have any (visible) effect (playing around with the values, nothing happens).

[image: Anti-Aliasing node in compositor]

Compare this with the output I get using the outdated [`ID Mask Node`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/id_mask.html):

[image: Anti-Aliasing with ID Mask node in compositor]

The edge looks much better now. Yet, this is not a real solution as this is only working with alpha values, so I can't get RGB out of this node.

I've also tried to play around with `Render > Film > Filter Size` but increasing the value does not give a good Anti-Aliasing result (here for `10.00px`):
[image: Bigger Filter Size]

Note I've seen [this SO question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208418/jagged-edges-in-eevee), which didn't help me. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73821/41169) lead me to the `ID Mask` node. [This](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/compositor-anti-aliasing-node-d2411/17570) is the UserFeedback during the development of the node in 2021. It looks exactly what I want to have: a global anti-aliasing for Eeevee getting rid of "jagged" edges.

Comment: This is related to how antialiasing works. Here you can see detailed explanation: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17844/aliased-edge-around-light-source-in-cycles I have nothing much to add.

Comment: @Crantisz Thanks a lot for the link, that solved my problem ✅

Comment: Hi, Splines, it looks as if this is solved, and a duplicate, so can be closed? Is that OK? (I hope your bounty rep. doesn't go to waste, though.. asking about that)

Comment: @RobinBetts Hey, sure, I've just awarded the bounty, so you can go ahead and mark this as duplicate and close it ;)

Comment: Cheers, @Splines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Plane with Emission material with Strength value of 100.
The rendered image have blown up white pixel values of 100 per each RGB channel.
Anti-Aliasing node expects as an input normalized RGB values (from 0 to 1 per channel).
There are two options.

- Save your image as PNG and apply the Anti-Aliasing to it.
  or
- Use the Normalize node before Anti-Aliasing node if your intention is to keep it black and white.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. The normalize node does work for black and white images. The reason I cranked up the emission strength to `100` is that a strength of `1` didn't appear white enough. Figured out that this is due to the Filmic (or the new AgX) view transform (see `Color Management`). For this project, I've now set it to `sRGB` where an emission strength of `1.0` corresponds to "full white" (`#ffffff`). Now, the anti-aliasing is working as expected even without any anti-aliasing node in the compositor ;)

Comment: You are welcome! I also stick with sRGB - Standard View  Color Management most of the time (for more stylized renders) and use the other options for complex lighting (usually in photorealistic renders)  or if I like the looks :)